# Replace closest values by average (or min/max) and keep exactly two rows by id if all values by id are equal

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
df_segments = 

         id  seg_length
15  000b994d-1a6b-4698-a270-b0f671b1e612        16.3
11  000b994d-1a6b-4698-a270-b0f671b1e612         1.1
3   000b994d-1a6b-4698-a270-b0f671b1e612         1.1
7   000b994d-1a6b-4698-a270-b0f671b1e612        16.3
31  016490a8-8740-4205-bfe4-c9fe45e853d3         1.0
27  016490a8-8740-4205-bfe4-c9fe45e853d3         1.4
19  016490a8-8740-4205-bfe4-c9fe45e853d3         1.4
23  016490a8-8740-4205-bfe4-c9fe45e853d3         1.0
39  05290fe1-ead2-462b-bbec-a7669eed7883         1.1
35  05290fe1-ead2-462b-bbec-a7669eed7883         1.4
47  05290fe1-ead2-462b-bbec-a7669eed7883         1.1
43  05290fe1-ead2-462b-bbec-a7669eed7883         1.4
63  0537a9e3-09c4-459c-a6e4-25694cfbacbd         1.1
59  0537a9e3-09c4-459c-a6e4-25694cfbacbd         1.4
51  0537a9e3-09c4-459c-a6e4-25694cfbacbd         1.4
55  0537a9e3-09c4-459c-a6e4-25694cfbacbd         1.1
71  05577c2e-da7d-4753-bba6-66762385e159         1.0
67  05577c2e-da7d-4753-bba6-66762385e159         5.4
79  05577c2e-da7d-4753-bba6-66762385e159         1.0
75  05577c2e-da7d-4753-bba6-66762385e159         5.4
1475  5a104c86-327e-466f-b14a-6953cacddcbb         0.5
1479  5a104c86-327e-466f-b14a-6953cacddcbb         0.5
1487  5a104c86-327e-466f-b14a-6953cacddcbb         0.5
1483  5a104c86-327e-466f-b14a-6953cacddcbb         0.5
2287  8e853797-a7f3-4605-8848-f6b211f9b055         2.1
2283  8e853797-a7f3-4605-8848-f6b211f9b055         2.1
2279  8e853797-a7f3-4605-8848-f6b211f9b055         2.1
2275  8e853797-a7f3-4605-8848-f6b211f9b055         2.1
3351  c1120018-c626-4c1b-81a5-476ce38f346b         0.6
3347  c1120018-c626-4c1b-81a5-476ce38f346b         1.2
3359  c1120018-c626-4c1b-81a5-476ce38f346b         0.5
3355  c1120018-c626-4c1b-81a5-476ce38f346b         1.2
```

All `id` have four row. For most `id`, dropping duplicates results in two rows. But for a few `id`s one of two things can happen:

1. Either all rows are equal, in which case `drop_duplicates()` will result in a single row.
2. `drop_duplicates()` with result in three or for rows because all values of `seg_length` are different.

However, all `seg_length` are the length of the sides in a rectangle (or very close to it) and squares. So, what I would like to do are the following things:

A. If all rows by id have the same `seg_length` value, keep two rows.

B. Replace the two largest (resp. smallest) values (by id) with their average. In other words:

```
df_segments = 

         id  seg_length
3351  c1120018-c626-4c1b-81a5-476ce38f346b         0.6
3347  c1120018-c626-4c1b-81a5-476ce38f346b         1.2
3359  c1120018-c626-4c1b-81a5-476ce38f346b         0.5
3355  c1120018-c626-4c1b-81a5-476ce38f346b         1.2
```

would become:

```
df_segments = 

         id  seg_length
3351  c1120018-c626-4c1b-81a5-476ce38f346b         0.55
3347  c1120018-c626-4c1b-81a5-476ce38f346b         1.2
3359  c1120018-c626-4c1b-81a5-476ce38f346b         0.55
3355  c1120018-c626-4c1b-81a5-476ce38f346b         1.2
```

Alternatively, use `min/max` if it is easier:

```
df_segments = 

         id  seg_length
3351  c1120018-c626-4c1b-81a5-476ce38f346b         0.6
3347  c1120018-c626-4c1b-81a5-476ce38f346b         1.2
3359  c1120018-c626-4c1b-81a5-476ce38f346b         0.6
3355  c1120018-c626-4c1b-81a5-476ce38f346b         1.2
```

I have tried to use `np.where` and define conditions but without any luck. I also tried to create a separate dataframe with the ids whose count was not 2 after dropping duplicates from the original dataframe, `df_segments` but I ended up in the same situation.

If anyone has an idea, I would be thankful for insights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand well, you want to average values 2 by 2 within each id. This also happens to do what you want when it’s 4 times the same value.

```
>>> averages = df.groupby('id')['seg_length'].apply(
... lambda s: s.sort_values().groupby([0, 0, 1, 1]).mean()
... )
>>> averages
id                                     
000b994d-1a6b-4698-a270-b0f671b1e612  0     1.10
                                      1    16.30
016490a8-8740-4205-bfe4-c9fe45e853d3  0     1.00
                                      1     1.40
05290fe1-ead2-462b-bbec-a7669eed7883  0     1.10
                                      1     1.40
0537a9e3-09c4-459c-a6e4-25694cfbacbd  0     1.10
                                      1     1.40
05577c2e-da7d-4753-bba6-66762385e159  0     1.00
                                      1     5.40
5a104c86-327e-466f-b14a-6953cacddcbb  0     0.50
                                      1     0.50
8e853797-a7f3-4605-8848-f6b211f9b055  0     2.10
                                      1     2.10
c1120018-c626-4c1b-81a5-476ce38f346b  0     0.55
                                      1     1.20
Name: seg_length, dtype: float64
```

If you want to keep the original shape, you can use `transform` (on both `groupby`s):

```
>>> replaced_seglengths = df.groupby('id')['seg_length'].transform(
... lambda s: s.sort_values().groupby([0, 0, 1, 1]).transform('mean')
... )
>>> replaced_seglengths
15       1.10
11       1.10
3       16.30
7       16.30
31       1.00
27       1.00
19       1.40
23       1.40
39       1.10
35       1.10
47       1.40
43       1.40
63       1.10
59       1.10
51       1.40
55       1.40
71       1.00
67       1.00
79       5.40
75       5.40
1475     0.50
1479     0.50
1487     0.50
1483     0.50
2287     2.10
2283     2.10
2279     2.10
2275     2.10
3351     0.55
3347     0.55
3359     1.20
3355     1.20
```

Finally replace the column in the dataframe:

```
>>> df['seg_length'] = replaced_seglengths
>>> df
                                        id  seg_length
15    000b994d-1a6b-4698-a270-b0f671b1e612        1.10
11    000b994d-1a6b-4698-a270-b0f671b1e612        1.10
3     000b994d-1a6b-4698-a270-b0f671b1e612       16.30
7     000b994d-1a6b-4698-a270-b0f671b1e612       16.30
31    016490a8-8740-4205-bfe4-c9fe45e853d3        1.00
27    016490a8-8740-4205-bfe4-c9fe45e853d3        1.00
19    016490a8-8740-4205-bfe4-c9fe45e853d3        1.40
23    016490a8-8740-4205-bfe4-c9fe45e853d3        1.40
39    05290fe1-ead2-462b-bbec-a7669eed7883        1.10
35    05290fe1-ead2-462b-bbec-a7669eed7883        1.10
47    05290fe1-ead2-462b-bbec-a7669eed7883        1.40
43    05290fe1-ead2-462b-bbec-a7669eed7883        1.40
63    0537a9e3-09c4-459c-a6e4-25694cfbacbd        1.10
59    0537a9e3-09c4-459c-a6e4-25694cfbacbd        1.10
51    0537a9e3-09c4-459c-a6e4-25694cfbacbd        1.40
55    0537a9e3-09c4-459c-a6e4-25694cfbacbd        1.40
71    05577c2e-da7d-4753-bba6-66762385e159        1.00
67    05577c2e-da7d-4753-bba6-66762385e159        1.00
79    05577c2e-da7d-4753-bba6-66762385e159        5.40
75    05577c2e-da7d-4753-bba6-66762385e159        5.40
1475  5a104c86-327e-466f-b14a-6953cacddcbb        0.50
1479  5a104c86-327e-466f-b14a-6953cacddcbb        0.50
1487  5a104c86-327e-466f-b14a-6953cacddcbb        0.50
1483  5a104c86-327e-466f-b14a-6953cacddcbb        0.50
2287  8e853797-a7f3-4605-8848-f6b211f9b055        2.10
2283  8e853797-a7f3-4605-8848-f6b211f9b055        2.10
2279  8e853797-a7f3-4605-8848-f6b211f9b055        2.10
2275  8e853797-a7f3-4605-8848-f6b211f9b055        2.10
3351  c1120018-c626-4c1b-81a5-476ce38f346b        0.55
3347  c1120018-c626-4c1b-81a5-476ce38f346b        0.55
3359  c1120018-c626-4c1b-81a5-476ce38f346b        1.20
3355  c1120018-c626-4c1b-81a5-476ce38f346b        1.20
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

use `np.select([conditions],[solutions])`

conditons

```
condition1=df2.groupby('id')['seg_length'].apply(lambda x:x.duplicated(keep=False))
condition2=df2.groupby('id')['seg_length'].apply(lambda x:~x.duplicated(keep=False))
```

Solution

```
sol1=df2['seg_length']
sol2=(df2.loc[condition2,'seg_length'].sum(0))/2

df2['newseg_length']=np.select([condition1,condition2],[sol1,sol2])

                     

          id                                      seg_length  newseg_length
3351  c1120018-c626-4c1b-81a5-476ce38f346b         0.6           0.55
3347  c1120018-c626-4c1b-81a5-476ce38f346b         1.2           1.20
3359  c1120018-c626-4c1b-81a5-476ce38f346b         0.5           0.55
3355  c1120018-c626-4c1b-81a5-476ce38f346b         1.2           1.20
```

Comment: Thank you. It solved part 2 of the problem.